# Netlogo 'towards' behaviour

Tags: netlogo

For a pursuit-evasion assignment I need to use the NetLogo command 'towards', but it doesn't seem to work, or I don't understand it.
What I think it should do: give the angle between the heading of the turtle and the line connecting the turtle with the target.
Here's the code for a simple model I made just to show the problem.

```
to set-up
  clear-all
  create-turtles 2
  ask turtle 0 [
    set xcor 0
    set ycor 0
    set shape "circle"
  ]
  ask turtle 1 [
    set xcor min-pxcor
    set ycor max-pycor
    set heading 135
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtle 0 [ fd 0.1 ]
  ask turtle 1 [ show towards turtle 0 ]
end
```

And here's a video of the behaviour. https://youtu.be/MUBiAypppc4 (I couldn't find a way to remove the audio without just replacing it using YouTube's current editing system, I'm sorry; you'll have to mute the audio yourself)
Examples of expected behaviour:
from 0:14 to 0:19, I would expect the number to gradually decrease, not increase
at about 0:38, I would expect the number to be 0, not somewhere around 300
between 0:38 and 0:42, I would expect the number to decrease or increase consistently, without those two sudden jumps

Is there a problem somewhere, or does 'towards' mean something different than I thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turtle 0 is moving and turtle 1 is reporting the direction to turtle 0. I think `towards` is working fine but you have forgotten about the world settings. For example, in the 14-19s part, the shortest path from 0 to 1 is down and left (about 220 heading), but that shortest path is with the world wrapped. Your turtles can move off one side and come in on the other (as you can see turtle 1 doing).

NetLogo measures distances and directions taking into account the wrapping configuration. It knows that the shortest path to get from turtle 0 to turtle 1 goes off the side and comes in the other, and reports the direction that the turtle would have to move to follow that path.

Create a link and you can see this. Revised code:

```
to set-up
  clear-all
  create-turtles 2
  ask turtle 0 [
    set xcor 0
    set ycor 0
    set shape "circle"
  ]
  ask turtle 1 [
    set xcor min-pxcor
    set ycor max-pycor
    set heading 135
    create-link-with turtle 0
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtle 0 [ fd 0.1 ]
  ask turtle 1 [ show towards turtle 0 ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although I don't quite understand. 'towards' is only about angle, right? Not about distance?

Comment: Also, how about the other examples? Those seem even stranger to me.

Comment: Yes, `towards` is about angle. But its the heading along the shortest path. Imagine you have two points immediately above each other, say at (0,-1) and (0,1) and you are standing at the lower point. You can look 'up' and see the other point (fairly close) or you can look 'down' and see past the lower edge, wrap past the upper edge and see the other point from 'above' but that would be a longer path. It is the same issue as going from Barcelona to Rome with a short easterly flight or a long westerly flight. Heading for `towards` is calculated using the shortest path.

Comment: See revised answer. If you have a link between the two turtles, you will be able to see the path used to derive the heading.

Comment: Thank you, that explains the sudden jumps! What still seemed wrong though, is the actual values: it didn't seem to be 0 at the right time. However, I think I figured out why: when rotating turtle 1, the number actually doesn't change! This surprises me. I can get what I was looking for in my question by doing `(towards turtle 0 - heading) modulo 360`.

Comment: The dictionary states "Reports the heading from this agent to the given agent." This is the absolute direction, not the direction relative to the agent's heading. Be careful with subtracting directions, you may need to go the other way. You may want to check out the NetLogo primitive `subtract-headings` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, but no, I don't, I already considered that. :)